# Firebase database listview open another activity

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database where I am saving data manually and retrieving data in the app and that is working well but I want that when user clicks the listview item that must open another activity and within that must retrieve another table.

Here is below my code

```
  private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

DatabaseReference mref = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
ListView mlistview;
ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
 mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
progressDialog.show();
                startActivity(new 
Intent(profilemain.this,profilemain.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                Toast.makeText(profilemain.this,"hi 
hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                Toast.makeText(profilemain.this,"hi 
hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_signout:

                Toast.makeText(profilemain.this,"You have successfully 
Signed out",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mAuth.signOut();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profilemain);
   progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
    progressDialog.setTitle("database is");

    mlistview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("users");
    //mref=new Firebase("https://stark-1dffd.firebaseio.com/users");
    arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    mlistview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    mref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            arrayList.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //

            //

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
                startActivity(new
                        Intent(profilemain.this,MainActivity.class));

            }
        }
    };



}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add an `ItemClickListener` on your `ListView`

```
 mlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MyActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("data", arrayList.get(position);// add the selected String from the ListView
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
```

and read the data from the other activity:

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
```

Comment: sir i want on item click must pass into another activity and that activity must show another table

Comment: that how you pass data from the item click and build the rest your own